issue in interfacing with terminal from node app
I am trying to build a node app which will provide a remote interface to my mobile phone.
The idea is to use child-process to spawn shell. But I can't understand how i'll give password inputs and perform multi-step process like rebasing git repo. My app's main focus is to make managing files and git repos remotely from your phone but I am having issues with i/o streams.
I have attached the code which is bare minimum to interact with the shell.
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const {WebSocketServer} = require('ws');
    const app = express();
    const process = require('process');
    const port = 3000;
    const host = '127.0.0.1';

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    let commandQueue = [];
    let currentChildProcess = null;
    let clients = [];    
    let currentPty = null;

    function startNextProcess() {
        if (commandQueue.length > 0 && !currentChildProcess) {

            const command = commandQueue.shift();
            const baseCommand = "cd '/mnt/c/Users/John/MyDocuments/NodePlayground'";
            const fullCommand = `${baseCommand} && ${command}`;

            currentChildProcess = spawn(fullCommand, {shell: true,stdio:"overlapped"});
        
            let stdoutData = '';
            let stderrData = '';

            currentChildProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                stdoutData += data.toString();
                clients.forEach((client) => {
                    client.send(stdoutData);
                });
            });

            currentChildProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
                stderrData += data.toString();
                clients.forEach((client) => {
                    client.send(stderrData);
                });
            });
        
            currentChildProcess.on('close', (code) => {
               console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
               console.log(`stdout: ${stdoutData}`);
               console.log(`stderr: ${stderrData}`);
                currentChildProcess = null;
                startNextProcess();
            });
        }
    
}


    const server = app.listen({port:port,host:host}, () => {
    console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
    const wss = new WebSocketServer({server:server,clientTracking: true});

    function messageHandler(message) {
        //console.log(`Received message => ${message}`);
        const json = JSON.parse(message.toString()); 
        const command = json.command;
        if(json.type==='start'){
            commandQueue.push(command);
            startNextProcess();
        }else{
            currentChildProcess.stdin.write(command);
            currentChildProcess.stdin.write('\n');
        }

        this.send('Command received');
    }

    wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
        clients.push(ws);
        ws.on('message', messageHandler);
        ws.send('Hello! Message From Server!!');
    });



I made something of sorts to interact with Vercel's build container. Can perform the tasks that you've mentioned.
It uses http & websockets.
However, since http connections are stateless, I had to do pipes and do command separations to perform a series of tasks.
You won't need that if you use websockets.
Here you go:
GitHub

I have a question. Are u able to perform password based interactions like in sudo command the input is not taken from stdin its from terminal interface.
